# Error: Handshake inactivity timeout (MySQL + Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, networking, handshake

Using docker-compose with ngnix, node backend and mysql.js. This error has occurred:

```
api      | there was an error connecting to pool:  Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
api      |     at Handshake.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:160:17)
api      |     at Handshake.emit (node:events:376:20)
api      |     at Handshake._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:124:8)
api      |     at Timer._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js:32:23)
api      |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
api      |     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
api      |     --------------------
api      |     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
api      |     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
api      |     at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
api      |     at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
api      |     at Pool.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
api      |     at /app/db/connect.js:18:10
api      |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
api      |     at Object.connectionFunc (/app/db/connect.js:17:21)
api      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/index.js:17:12)
api      |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14) {
api      |   code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
api      |   fatal: true,
api      |   timeout: 10000
api      | }
```

As another post mentioned, I tried changing the timeout and that didn't work.

I have to use a network to connect my docker-compose files. I've intermittently had it working without using an internal network, but other times I get the following message:

`ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network`

This itself is strange as there are only the 3 default networks (and one I have created). Other posts have said that if you go over 30 or more networks this should become an issue -

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:~/blog/blog# docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME       DRIVER    SCOPE
430e230e6641   bridge     bridge    local
915d73adee82   host       host      local
8cd9e79fd644   none       null      local
9f936dc688b7   underdev   bridge    local
```

So i.e. I've tried this in my docker-compose.yml

```
  db:
    container_name: db
    build: ./db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=True
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=secret
      - MYSQL_USER=secret
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - underdev
volumes:
  db_data: {}
networks:
 underdev:
  external: true
```

I've also tried this:

```
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.57.0/24
```

Both fix the ipv4 error, but then I still get the handshake inactivity timeout error. Someone suggested using `network_mode: bridge`, but shouldn't the network use the default bridge automatically? If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

PS:

Here is the connection to the db - I tried adding a timeout to the connection handler - the timeout worked, but the connection still didn't have a handshake.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
  var testconnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'db',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root',
    password: process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
    database: 'blog',
    debug: true
  })
  var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host            : 'db',
    port            : '3306',
    //connectTimeout  : 20000,
    //acquireTimeout  : 20000,
    //timeout         : 20000,
    user            : 'root',
    password        : process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
    database        : 'blog'
  });
  console.log("-----------------------------------------------------");
  console.log("value of testconnection: ", testconnection);
  console.log("-----------------------------------------------------");
  testconnection.query("SELECT * from blogs", function(err, rows, fields){
    console.log("value of err: ", err);
    console.log("value of rows: ", rows);
    console.log("value of fields: ", fields);
  })
  console.log("-----------------------------------------------------");
  console.log("value of pool: ", pool);
  console.log("-----------------------------------------------------");
  let poolPromise = new Promise(resolve=>{
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM blogs", function(err,rows,fields){
      /*
      console.log("value or err: ", err);
      console.log('value of rows: ', rows);
      console.log('value of fields: ', fields);
      */
      if (err){
        console.log('there was an error connecting to pool:', err);
        process.exit();
        resolve(false);
      }else{
        resolve(pool);
      }
    })
  })

  return poolPromise;
}

module.exports = {
  connectionFunc
}
```

EDIT:

I've written scripts to completely uninstall and completely reinstall docker (including all folders and subdirectories) and I still have the following error message:

`ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network`

Here is script to remove all of docker:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce

sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
```

And here is the script I use to install docker (which I confirm works with the hello world test) and comes from commands in this page of the documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/):

```
#!/bin/bash
  

echo 'apt-get update'
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
sudo apt-get update
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'sudo apt-get install'
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
yes | sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common
echo 'curl software'
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'add-apt-repository'
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
echo 'sudo apt-get update'
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
sudo apt-get update
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'install docker-ce-cli'
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
yes | sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

EDIT:

Adding a links variable to tha api container in the docker-compose file didn't fix the issue:

```
    networks:
      - underdev
    links:
      - db:db
```

EDIT:

Tried rebooting the server. That didn't work, same error. I've also tried
upgrading the server via

```
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and running the application again - same error.

I'm currently running 18.04.5 ubuntu bionic:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Tried upgrading to 20.04.1 and that also doesn't work.

---

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in another way.
It wasn't an inbound issue.
I'm using 'Standard TCP/IP over SSH' in order to connect Mysql-server in AWS.
There is no problem normally. But suddenly it happended.

"Handshake inactivity timeout"!!

I found out that another application is binding port 3306 of the development environment.
You can use command 'netstat -anb'.
After deleting it and reconnecting 'Standard TCP/IP over SSH' again, the problem went away.